# Erro ao acessar banco mysql no azure

Tags: php, mysql, microsoft-azure

Apos criar um novo usuário não consigo acesso o meu banco mysql no azure.
Como posso reverter esse erro?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Isso é um MySQL In App? Vc apenas criou um novo usuário, ou também alterou algo do usuario padrão, como trocar a senha/desabiliar?

Comment: isso mesmo...estranho que depois de uma hora tudo voltou ao normal...

Comment: Estou precisando de ajudar para realizar uma query do tipo select = "SELECT * FROM cursos"; esta voltando nulo...

Comment: Eu fiz duas perguntas, para qual delas a resposta é "isso mesmo'?

Comment: Isso é um MySQL In App: SIM

Comment: Vc apenas criou um novo usuário: SIM

Comment: Legal, bom saber desse bug. Vou tentar reproduzir e enviar para o time revisar. O problema deve ter sido temporário e pontual, não requer demais configurações. Obrigado!

Comment: Quanto a query ??? Tem como mim ajudar nisso ??

Comment: Tem, mas é outra pergunta. Faça uma nova pergunta aqui no SO e pode postar o link aqui que dou uma olhada.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/209052/como-executar-uma-query-no-azure